# How to prioritize main pyqt5 thread in python3?

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, pyqt5, thread-priority

I have made a gui application with PyQt5 in python 3.8. But when I order from my GUI to perform heavy multithreaded CPU-intensive task (the gui thread isn't engaged), the GUI becomes very non-responsive (most likely due to CPU being concentrated on worker tasks).

My question is, is there any way to prioritize gui's thread in python so that workers don't slow the GUI down? I use `threading.Thread(target=task, daemon=True).start()` to run threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thread priority is not something you can do, but there are a few ways around it to have a responsive GUI.

1. change [sys.setswitchinterval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setswitchinterval) to a lower value (perhaps to 0.001)

which makes python switch threads more frequently so the GUI can respond more quickly to events, and will feel more responsive.

2. use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of threading for computations.

aside from the fact that you get to use more CPU cores, you also get to control the affinity and priority of each process, so you can guarantee your GUI stays a higher priority even on a loaded system.

3. release the GIL more often

usually if you have a choice between an operation being done in python and another being done in a C extension (like numpy or pandas), the C extension can release the GIL, so your GUI can hold the GIL for a longer time.

out of the above solutions, the one most used (even in non-python programs) is using multiprocessing, as it has more benefits than just "responsive GUI", the third one is more of a "recommendation while coding", so keep it in mind when coding the application.

Comment: Multiprocessing will use more cores? so threading doesn't use all cores if I make proper amount of threads?

Comment: @AmaeSaeki python itself uses only 1 core when using threading due to the GIL, you can use more cores if whatever code you are using allows it by dropping the gil, (like calling code from dlls or a few numpy functions like matrix multiplication), but it's not something that "python" does on its own without an extension allowing it, and you still get contention on the GIL, which ultimately makes the GUI less reponsive, while using multiprocessing just "create another GIL" which reduces any contention on it.

Comment: Now i get why making more threads didn't speed up my calculation as I thought it would haha! I will definitely go with multiprocessing then! Thanks for your help! Giving upvote!